# Postgres SQL - Column does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, column-alias

```
SELECT nmemail as order_email, 
       dtorder, 
       vlOrder, 
       cohorts.cohortdate 
FROM   factorderline 
       JOIN (SELECT nmemail as cohort_email, Min(dtorder) AS cohortDate FROM  factorderline GROUP  BY cohort_email limit 5) cohorts 
ON order_email= cohort_email limit 5;
```

> ERROR:  column "order_email" does not exist

What is the problem with this query?

Comment: err, crap, sorry about the accidental vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that the definition of the column alias hasn't been parsed at the time the join is evaluated; use the actual column name instead:

```
SELECT nmemail as order_email, 
       dtorder, 
       vlOrder, 
       cohorts.cohortdate 
FROM   factorderline 
JOIN (
  SELECT nmemail as cohort_email, Min(dtorder) AS cohortDate 
  FROM  factorderline 
  GROUP BY cohort_email limit 5
) cohorts ON nmemail = cohort_email 
limit 5;
```

Also, when using `limit`, you really should use an `order by` clause.

From the docs:

> When using LIMIT, it is important to use an ORDER BY clause that
>   constrains the result rows into a unique order. Otherwise you will get
>   an unpredictable subset of the query's rows.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that output column names can't be used in joins.

From [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-SELECT-LIST):

> An output column's name can be used to refer to the column's value in ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses, but not in the WHERE or HAVING clauses; there you must write out the expression instead.